How to use vgrename and allow booting into the renamed volume group that is encrypted?
All prior answers do not work for me.
Environment: ubuntu 24.04, wayland, debian/gnome base, 6.11 kernel, EFI boot, nvme, encrypted, ubuntu -default install using installer, nvmen0p1 (EFI), p2 (boot), p3 (root - user), currently cannot boot into the nvme and drops into init prompt, cannot luksOpen from there and gives me an error for nvme0p3.
Goal: change ubuntu-vg to restore-vg from live ubuntu USB
What to change: vgname, grub, fstab, cryptab?
What i achieved: vgrename, grub config manually changed with restore-vg, chroot to run update-grub. The problem is that /etc/crypttab has the drive correctly identified by UUID why would it be looking for volume names? My fstab also uses NO volume names, only UUIDs.
Where it continually fails is initramfs-udpate -c command due to cryptsetup not finding new volume group mount in mapper. Somehow cryptsetup needs to be run again to identify the correct root volume.
FYI: how to chroot to update grub, and ramfs LUKS/Cryptosetup and LVM: can't input passwords after boot
